# Prevent react-router history.push from reloading current route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm taking my first steps with `react-router`.

I'm currently using the `hashHistory` for development purposes and I'm performing 'manual' navigation. That is to say, I'm *not* using `Link` and I'm invoking `history.push('/some/route');` in order to navigate (in response to plain old clicks on anchor tags).

What I'm noticing is that, even when I'm already on the target route, `react-router` will re-render the relevant target component every time `history.push('/target/route');` is invoked: On every `push('/target/route')`:

- the fragment part of the URL remains `#/target/route`
- the query string part of the URL changes to `?_k=somethingRandom`
- the target component re-renders

I would like for that re-rendering to *not* happen - I actually expected `history.push` to be a no-op when I'm already at the route that I'm attempting to `push`.

I'm apparently missing something, as this is not what's happening. Funnily enough I'm seeing posts from people who are trying to *achieve* the behaviour that I'd like to get rid of - they'd like to 'refresh' a route without leaving it, so to speak. Which looks pretty much like the opposite problem :).

Could you enlighten me as to what it is I'm misunderstanding and how I would achieve the desired behaviour? Is this perhaps something that would go away if (when) I switch to `browserHistory`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that your component re-renders because something in your `prop` changes when you make a router push. I suspect it might be the `action` or `key` properties of `prop.location`. You could always check all the values of `prop` during each render to see what changes.

You can solve this issue by comparing your old route path with the new one in the `shouldComponentUpdate` life-cycle method. If it hasn't changed you are on the same route, and you can prevent the re-rendering by returning `false`. In all other cases, return `true`. By default this always returns true.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.props.route.path == nextProps.route.path) return false;
  return true;
}
```

You'll have to make further checks as well as this will prevent your component from updating on `state` updates within the component as well, but I guess this would be your starting point.

Read more about `shouldComponentUpdate` on the official [**react docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) page.

> Use this as an opportunity to return false when you're certain that the transition to the new props and state will not require a component update.

Comment: Spot on. A peek into the props reveals a whole bunch of properties which are specific to react-router and change on history.push(). And yes, action and key do differ across invocations of shouldComponentUpdate. Upvoted and accepted. The proposed solution does makes sense - however, taking into account the actual state changes that will need to be accounted for, I think it's 'too late in the code path' to be handling this - I'll end up doing a whole lot of redundant diffing in every 'top level' component. Perhaps I should avoid push()-ing that route into the history in the first place ..

Comment: This doesn't work for React router v4, it needs to use `location.search`

Comment: This answer is only relevant to React Class-based components. For functional components you can wrap them with `React.memo` to achieve *shallow-props-comparing* which will not re-render the component wrapped, cause it is not aware of deep props changes, **unless** the `route` prop itself is a completely new Object each time...

Comment: I'm using functional component. and tried React.memo but not worked.

Answer (score 3):

I will give this a shot...

If you land here and looking to change your URL (for sharing purposes for example) then [RR docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components) already has the solution described. Just make sure you do not use the history within the component (i.e. `this.props.history.push()`)as you will be (as expected) routed to the target. You are however allowed to access `your` browser history without any interference with the component's `history`.

Following tested only on Chrome

```
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

and then from your XYZ component

```
// XYZ.js
import React from 'react';
import history from './history'

class XYZ extends React.Component {
    _handleClick() {
        // this should not cause rerender and still have URL change 
        history.push("/someloc");
    }
    render() {
        return(
          <button onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>test </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and i find the (dumb) solution.

You just have a `<button>` (button by default is `type=submit`) or something similar (form, submit.... etc) thats is reloading the page like a html `<form method=GET ...>`.

Check it in your code, and remove it.

PD:
`_k=somethingRandom` > this is just the value inputs (or the button) that you are sending in the form.

Answer (score 1):

In `App.js`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.location.search === this.props.location.search
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier workaround maybe replacing the Route with our own route

```js
import { Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function MyRoute({ key, path, exact, component: Component, history }) {
  let lastLocation = null;
  return (
    <Route
      key={key}
      path={path}
      exact={exact}
      render={(props) => {
        history.listen((location) => {
          lastLocation = location;
        });

        // monkey patching to prevent pushing same url into history stack
        const prevHistoryPush = history.push;
        history.push = (pathname, state = {}) => {
          if (
            lastLocation === null ||
            pathname !==
              lastLocation.pathname + lastLocation.search + lastLocation.hash ||
            JSON.stringify(state) !== JSON.stringify(lastLocation.state)
          ) {
            prevHistoryPush(pathname, state);
          }
        };
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default withRouter(MyRoute);
```

We use this as a wrapper for actual Route of react-router-dom and it works perfectly for me.
for more please refer [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/470)

Comment: This solution likely works, though watch out:  `const prevHistoryPush = history.push;` is in the render loop which means it will add a call to the stack every render.  That's a memory leak that will eventually leading to a function depth error.

Answer (score -3):

tsx sample

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';  
export const history = createBrowserHistory();


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```