# How to handle react History.Push() causing undesired component remounts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

**Problem**

Calling `history.push()` inside of a component seems to cause the entire react component to unmount and remount; causing pointless remote service calls.

Specifically, I have a remote service call that fires on component entry. *I do not want the component to remount, and I don't want the service call to re-run (its slow).*

It seems like `history.push(location.pathname + '?' + encodeURI(urlSearchParams.toString()));` is going to cause an unmount *no matter what*. Am I using it incorrectly? Is there a better approach for tracking the history of a users' filter changes and not having to worry about extraneous service calls?

**Intent**

I'm utilizing `history.push()` to keep the browser history updated with changes to the query params. The query params control filtering of table data, e.g. **?sort=asc&isCompleted=true**, etc.

When a user changes their filtering settings, I intend for the *existing* table data stored in state to simply be filtered, rather than re-loading the data remotely and forcing the user to sit and wait. I also want a user to be able to share a URL to another user with the appropriate filters included.

**What I've Tried**

- Tried dropping history.push() altogether, using only state. This works, but means its not possible to have a sharable URL with the filters appended as query params.
- Tried tinkering with useEffect() and useRef() but was frustrated by the incessant remounting.

**Component Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

export const WidgetTable = () => {
  let urlSearchParams = useQuery();
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  const [originalTableData, setOriginalTableData] = useState<TableData| undefined>(undefined);
  const [filteredTableData, setFilteredTableData] = useState<TableData| undefined>(undefined);

  // go get the table data from the remote service
  const fetchTableData = async () => {
   <- go remotely fetch table data and then set originalTableData ->
  }

  // triggered when a user sets a filter on the table (updates the data displayed in the table)
  const filterTableData = () => {
   <- filter the existing table data in state and then set the filterdTableData ->
  }

  // also triggered when a user sets a filter on the table (updates the URL in the browser)
  const setFilter = (filterToSet: ReleasePlanFilterType, value: string) => {
    switch (filterToSet) {
      case ReleasePlanFilterType.Target: {
        if (urlSearchParams.get(filterToSet)) {
          urlSearchParams.set(filterToSet, value);
        } else {
          urlSearchParams.append(filterToSet, value);
        }
        break;
      }
      <snip>
    }

   // We've set the filter in the query params, but persisting this to the history causes a reload :(
   history.push(location.pathname + '?' + encodeURI(urlSearchParams.toString())); 
  
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTableData();
  }, []);

  return (<snip> a fancy table and filtering controls <snip>);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, after reading through several other similar stack overflow questions, there doesn't seem to be a way to not remount (rerender) the component. The history changes automatically causes a prop change from how react router dom handles things under the hood. Most of these questions that I find used class components and the answer was to use shouldComponentUpdate to see if the previous path was equal to the new path. If they were equal then they would return, essentially making it so they wouldn't rerender.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.props.route.path == nextProps.route.path) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Source: [Prevent react-router history.push from reloading current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896855/prevent-react-router-history-push-from-reloading-current-route)

So now the issue would be converting this to work with hooks. I'll need to run some tests, but I believe this should work for your use case.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchTableData();
}, [location.pathname]);
```

By adding `location.pathname` as a dependency, this effect should then only be called when the pathname actually changes.

Comment: Using location.pathname doesn't seem to work as expected. Is it possible that components above, or below this could be causing unmount for similar reasons? For example if the parent also has props for location, would it not also trigger an unmounting?

Comment: @Ray what is happening that it doesn't seem to work as expected? I've tried a simple example through codesandbox and it seems to be working. Also your example seems to work as it should. There may be other components wrapping this that are causing the unmount/remount. Are you able to provide a codesandbox with the wrapping components?

Comment: Effectively getting the same behavior, changing a filter and calling history.push() fires that useEffect, even with location.pathname set as described. This component is several layers deep - its possible one of the parent components is the problem. Is there a way to diagnose if one of the parents is suspect? Several of the parent components make use of history as well. I can try and replicate it in a sandbox, but I'll need some time to untangle any "Work specific" code.

Comment: After some poking around, I found that a parent component was using component='WidgetTable'. Switching it to render, along with the change you suggested, now results in the correct behavior!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working. I was going to send you my Codesandbox a bit ago, but a meeting came up.

Answer (score 6):

After hours and hours of debugging I managed to solve this by using:

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Home />
</Route>
```

Instead of:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

This works with `react-router` v5.

Comment: I confirm this is what I saw as well. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I believe that this is a bug in the library.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer! This saved my day

Comment: This is also a great answer, its just that the first answer solved the particular problem in my unique case. However both answers seem useful so thank you!